# #define, #ifdef #undef #endif

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have the following code

```
#define PROC_ADD

void main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
#ifdef PROC_ADD
// Do this code here then undefined it to run the code in the else
// processing work
#undef PROC_ADD
#else
// now that PROC_ADD has been undefined run this code
// processing work
#endif
    }
}
```

However, it will run the code. But it won't run the code in the `else` after the `PROC_ADD` has been undefined.

I think the reason could be that you can only define and undefine at compile time, and not at run-time. However, I am not really sure.

Comment: Please note the preprocessing doesn't happen at runtime, the `undef` doesn't happen at runtime. It happens at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the build time equivalent of:

```
int x = 1;

int main()
{
    if (x)
    {
        ...
        x = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

*ifdef*, etc. happen at build time, but for your example, that's not an issue.  Once you evaluate the *if* (either the runtime or build-time form), the decision about which branch to take it made.  Changing something after the decision has been made does not change that decision.

Comment: Isn't #ifdef pre-processed before the compilation?

Comment: @Suresh - yes, pre-processing does take place before compilation.  But since compilers automatically invoke the pr-processor, I don't think the distinction is important for question such as these.  That said, I'll change my answer to use "build-time" instead of "compile-time" to be more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

`#define`s only work during preprocessing. So

```
#define PROC_ADD 
void main(void) 
{
#ifdef PROC_ADD 
// Do this code here then undefined it to run the code in the else 
// processing work 
#undef PROC_ADD 
#else 
// now that PROC_ADD has been undefined run this code 
// processing work 
#endif 
}
```

will be processed the following way: since `PROC_ADDR` is defined the preprocessor will completely exclude the `#else` branch and then execute `#undef`, so the `#else` branch code never survives preprocessing and never reaches the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The `ifdef` condition is evaluated when the preprocessor gets to it. When you `undef` `PROC_ADD` inside the `ifdef`'d code, the preprocessor has already decided which section of code to include and which to ignore.

Furthermore, yes: `ifdef`, `undef`, etc are processed at pre-processing time -- the compiler never even sees these so-called directives. This of course means run-time code never sees these directives either.

The preprocessor works by taking a single pass through the text file. The preprocessor does not even care that your text file happens to contain C code! It has zero knowledge that your `ifdef`s and `else`s and whatnot happen to be inside a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the code represented by the second comment section to *always* run, just do

```
#ifdef PROC_ADD
// Do the stuff to be done if PROC_ADD is defined
#undef PROC_ADD
#endif
// Do the stuff to always be done
```

If you want run-time behaviour changes, you must use run-time constructs (such as a variable to serve as a flag). As we are all saying ;), pre-processor directives are evaluated once only, at compile time.

Comment: I have edited my post. That was just a short example. However, the code itself would run in a loop. However, on the first loop I would like to run the first if statement. Then on the second and subsequent loops I don't won't to enter the if but go into the else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In just about every programming language or syntax, once execution has entered one branch of a conditional (in this case, the conditional being `#ifdef`, even if the condition changes during execution of the branch, other branches will never be executed.

I'm sure you wouldn't expect this to print "Hello", would you?

```
if (i == 1)
    i = 0;
else
    printf("Hello\n");
```

Basically what you're saying is that the code under the `else` branch should always execute, then just take it out of a branch, and **put it directly in the code**.

Both the compiler and the execution only make one pass through conditionals, once a match has been found they look no further.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: the `else` portion of the following code is not executed, even though `x` has been set to `false` in the `if` section.

The condition is checked in the `if(x)` line itself. Once it enters that block, it doesn't recalculate each of the subsequent `else` sections. The compiler has already made a decision on that.

```
bool x = true;
if(x)
{
  // Do something
  x = false;
}
else
{
  // Else code
}
```