# Templates: Only execute method if class has it

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

I want to write a function which executes the method of some templated class, but should also compile fine if the class doesn't have it. In that case, it should just not call the function.

```
struct A
{
   void func() {}
};

struct B
{
};

template <typename T>
void anotherFunc(T t)
{
   //do t.func() here if T implements func, just do nothing if it doesn't.
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Google for SFINAE and C++11 (if you are using it).

Comment: see also [is there an equivalent for __if_exists in gnu C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779466/is-there-an-equivalent-for-if-exists-in-gnu-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// type_sink takes a type, and discards it.  type_sink_t is a C++1y style using alias for it
template<typename T> struct type_sink { typedef void type; };
template<typename T> using type_sink_t = typename type_sink<T>::type;

// has_func is a traits class that inherits from `true_type` iff the expression t.func()
// is a valid one.  `std::true_type` has `::value=true`, and is a good canonical way to
// represent a compile-time `bool`ean value.
template<typename T,typename=void> struct has_func : std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct has_func<
  T,
  type_sink_t< decltype( std::declval<T&>().func() ) >
> : std::true_type {};

// helpers for tag dispatching.
namespace helper_ns {
  template<typename T> void anotherFunc( T&& t, std::false_type /* has_func */ ) {}
  template<typename T> void anotherFunc( T&& t, std::true_type /* has_func */ ) {
    std::forward<T>(t).func();
  }
}
// take the type T, determine if it has a .func() method.  Then tag dispatch
// to the correct implementation:
template<typename T> void anotherFunc(T t) {
  helper_ns::anotherFunc( std::forward<T>(t), has_func<T>() );
}
```

is a C++11 solution that does tag dispatching on a traits class that determines if `t.func()` is a valid expression.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Why what?

Comment: @Yakk: Why do you need the `type_sink`? Removing it and leaving just the `decltype(std::declval<T&>().func())` seems to work.

Comment: @JanHudec It's a good solution, but I was expecting something more idiomatic like `template<typename T>
auto helper(T&& t) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().f(), void()) { t.f(); }

void helper(...) { }`

Comment: @0x499602D2: What about making it an answer? That does look much simpler and seems sufficient.

Comment: @Yakk I also am not trying to be rude. I apologize if you're getting that impression.

Comment: @user3521733 won't work if `func()` returns non-`void`.  So you need to deal with that.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I like doing one thing at a time when writing template meta programming.  `type_sink` takes a type and throws it away.  `has_func` checks if `t.func()` is a valid expression, then feeds it to a `type_sink`, in the `true` specialization.  Finally, we avoid function `template` specialization and SFINAE in function invocation and use tag dispatching, which is far easier to debug, and scales better than raw SFINAE.  Do one thing at a time, and do it robustly.  Each piece can be understood on its own as a bonus.

Comment: And now with comments for each part of the code.  As an aside, @0x499602d2, what happens if I pass a non-standard layout type to C style `...` functions again?  I forget.

Comment: @Yakk I didn't go so far as to take that into account but we can still protect against that overload being called by using an `std::enable_if<>` guard with `std::is_standard_layout<>`

Comment: @mooingduck I'd do `template<class T>std::result_of_t< callFunc(T&& t, int)->decltype(std::forward<T>t.func()){return t.func();} void callFunc(T&& t,...){} callFunc` instead (as we know `int` can be passed to `...` safely).  But at this point, why not just do tag dispatching?

Comment: @Yakk: Because then you have to figure out how to come up with a tag, and I've never liked any existing methods for detecting members automatically.  FirstChoice + SecondChoice + SFINAE is just much simpler to understand.  Also easily extendable.

Comment: @Yakk: So I tried it with a `func()` that returns a type: `struct A { int func() { return 1; } };`, and it seems to fail with or without the `type_sink`.

Comment: @user3521733 compiler?  (and make sure `const`ness and `T`'s type are consistent)

Comment: @Yakk: I tried it with g++ 4.9.0, clang++ 3.4, and g++ 4.8.1. The code is http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c2a7c546b2df240.

Comment: @user3521733 oops, typo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c6bb1e76263c56e -- `type_sink` is supposed to map everything to `void` after evaluating the type -- it is a 'sink', a place where types go away.  I did `typedef T type` instead of `typedef void type`.  Fixed above, link to live example.

Comment: I thought `std::forward` only works with a universal reference.

Comment: @kec it is usually used with universal references.  I would write the above differently today: I would probably use a universal reference in `anotherFunc` add some `decay_t`, use `void(expression)` instead of `type_sink<>`, change how I wrote `has_func`, and a bunch of other changes.